# convert elements inside a string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

here is my code

```
DECLARE @DaysOfWeek VARCHAR(7) 
SET @DaysOfWeek='0000000' 
SELECT LEFT(@DaysOfWeek, (7-1)) 

               + '1' 

               + RIGHT(@DaysOfWeek, Len(@DaysOfWeek)-7) AS 

               DaysOfWeek
```

and the output  am getting is **0000001**,also if i provide 6 instead of 7 the output will be **0000010**.But what i reqiured for first case the desired output will be **0000007** and for second case **0000060** ie;replace 1 with its positional value..Any idea?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what the desired results are?

Answer (score 0):

here is the code which i required...

```
DECLARE @DaysOfWeek VARCHAR(7) 
SET @DaysOfWeek='0000000' 
SELECT LEFT(@DaysOfWeek, (7-1)) 

           + convert(varchar(1),c.dayoftheweek)  

           + RIGHT(@DaysOfWeek, Len(@DaysOfWeek)-7) AS 

           DaysOfWeek
```